# rails loop through linked records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After working through many rails tutorials this is my first solo project

Ive got two models, one controls top level records(lesson.rb) and the other controls related images via carrierWave(attachment.rb).  I'm trying to loop through the linked images and display them with the post.

So far I have asset creation working, but Im having a hard time figuring out how to display the connected images in show.html.erb.  Forgive me if the answer is stupid easy, ive googled this extensively and while I have found many results im still having a hard time applying the methods to my project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**/models/lesson.rb**

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :attachments_attributes

  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments

  validates :title, :content, :presence => true
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true

end
```

**/models/attachment.rb**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  belongs_to :lesson
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**/controllers/lessons.rb(show method)**

```
  def show
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**/views/lessons/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="body sixteen columns">
    <h2><%= @lesson.title %></h2>

    <div class="sixteen columns images">
        <% for image in @lesson.attachment %>
            <%= image_tag @lesson.attachment.image_url.to_s %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <p><%= simple_format(@lesson.content) %></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: use `each` to iterate through the attachments, and refer to `attachments` as plural instead of singular.

```
<% @lesson.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
  <%= image_tag attachment.image_url.to_s %>
<% end>
```

Another good thing to do is:

`@lesson = Lesson.includes(:attachments).find(params[:id])`

If you use `includes` when retrieving the lesson from the database, it will only fire one SQL SELECT query instead of one + the number of attachments on that lesson. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations for more detail.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, i'm still getting used to the rails way and I guess it shows.